# Sending temperature value from sensor to Web-Page using Flask, Nginx and Raspberry-Pi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, raspberry-pi3

I am working with Raspberry-PI,DHT22 Sensor , Flask Template and Nginx Web-server. I wrote and ran this code **test.py** :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():

    import sys
    import Adafruit_DHT
    humidity,temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.AM2302, 18)
    if temperature is not None:        
        return render_template("index.html",temp=('{0:0.1f}*'.format(temperature)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True,port=8080)
```

Here is the **index.html** code snippet :

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>Current Temperature : {{temp}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

After running **test.py**. I am getting this kind of error onto the WEBPAGE -

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

#### **Please help me out and resolve this problem**

Answer (score 1):

You arent passing the temp var on. Change `return render_template("index.html")` to `return render_template("index.html", temp=temp)`

Comment: Sorry, i did forget to write this statement here but now you can see the whole correct format of program. @Qwerty

Comment: Please suggest me some solutions for this problem!

Comment: @krish0456 I reccomend using a try, except as Exception block to find out what the actual error is